# List Changing In Python

Tags: python, list

```
[(946871.62999999884, [303.91000000000003]), (964918.62999999884, [353.75]),  
 (965117.81999999878, [356.98000000000002]), (959944.86999999883, [528.53999999999996])]
```

I have a list that looks like this. I was wondering if there was any way to remove the minilist, so that it would look like

```
[(946871.62999999884, 303.91000000000003), (964918.62999999884, 353.75),  
 (965117.81999999878, 356.98000000000002), (959944.86999999883, 528.53999999999996)]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```
L = [(x, y[0]) for x, y in L]
```

Comment: Python claims that I have a list error: list index out of range. Is this this full answer or do I have to do some work on my own? @Cat Plus Plus @g.d.d.c

Comment: @GodOnlyKnows: Then your input looks differently than what you've showed us.

Comment: @god-only-knows - if you're getting a list index then your initial list isn't regular.  It would imply that at some point in your outer list of tuples there is an entry that lacks an inner list for the second value.

Comment: Oh, thanks GDDC. There were two values that were left blank for some reason. Thanks so much to both of you :)

Comment: @cat plus plus @g.d.d.c For future reference, is there any easy way to get rid of those blank values? Thanks.

Comment: @god-only-knows - It kind of depends on what the erroneous value in the outer list looks like.  You can add a conditional check to the end of the list comprehension like so: `[(x, y[0]) for x, y in L if y]`. If `y` is Falsey (0, '', None, [], {}) then the entry won't be included in the new list.

Answer (score 4):

This should do that:

```
newList = [(x, y[0]) for x, y in oldList]
```

Comment: Python claims that I have a list error: list index out of range. Is this this full answer or do I have to do some work on my own?